# Pegar valores a un dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

alguien me puede ayudar con lo siguiente?
Digamos que tengo una lista de dimension 100 llamanda "punto" y tengo otra de dimension 50 llamada "linea", y en total tengo 150 datos, de los cuales 100 le corresponde punto y los otros 50 les corresponde linea, y yo quiero crear un dataframe con dimension 150 y tener una columna para punto y otra para linea y si no hay dato en punto o linea que le corresponda un NaN o un 0, pero a la hora de crearlo no me deja ya que todas las columnas deben de tener la misma dimension al parecer, como le puedo hacer?

Comment: O sea, ¿quieres un dataframe de 100 filas en el que que la columna "punto" tenga 100 valores, mientras que la columna "linea" tenga solo 50 valores y otros 50 NaN? ¿Dónde irían esos NaN? ¿Después de los primeros 50? ¿Antes? ¿Por el medio? ¿O quieres que el dataframe tenga 150 filas, y la columna "punto" tenga 100 datos y luego 50 NaN, mientras que la columna "linea" comienza por 100 NaN y luego tiene 50 datos?

Comment: En Python no puedes tener listas con dimensiones predefinidas. Quieres decir que tiene algo pero vas a sustituirlo por los 100 o 50 valores, no?
Que has intentado hasta ahora? Pon código para que podamos ayudarte a arreglar el problema!

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia, he resuelto mi problema, lo que hice fue que a la lista "punto" le puse 50 valores np.nan al final y a la lista "linea" le puse 100 valores np.nan al principio para que ambas tuvieran la misma dimension con la libreria numpy usando np.nan y np.empty, para despues hacerlos dataframe sin problema, pero ahora tengo otro problema...

Digamos que ya importe mi archivo a python y ya lo converti a dataframe y ya le hice varias cosas para estructurarlo mejor, y hasta ahi todo bien, pero ahora, le tengo que hacer lo mismo a 20 archivos iguales al mismo tiempo y luego concatenar todos en un mismo dataframe para luego exportarlo a una base de datos, asi que intente usar algun ciclo for para concatenar todos las filas(quiero concatenar las filas ya que todos los archivos tienen las mismas columnas) solo que he tenido algunos errores, les anexo mi codigo

```
document = ET.parse('0500.xml')
root = document.getroot()
items = root.findall('.//item')
```

ahi importo el archivo xml y digamos que tengo los archivos [0500.xml,0600.xml,0700.xml...] y ya luego de hacerle varias cosas lo convierto en dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns=['fecha','hora','latitud','altitud',
'latitud_1','altitud_1','latitud_2','altitud_2'],index=range(1,len(items)+1))
```

y digamos que la unica cosa que cambia de un archivo a otro es que por ejemplo, yo tengo una columna llamada "hora" y al  dataframe del archivo "0500.xml" la tengo que llenar esa columna "hora" de "0500", al archivo "0600.xml" llenar su columna "hora" con "0600" y asi sucesivamente, y todo lo demas es lo mismo para cada archivo, por eso creo que no seria bueno juntarlos antes de empezar a trabajar con ellos, espero me puedan ayudan a ver como estructurar algun ciclo for que pueda leer varios archivoso ver si hay otra manera para trabajar, gracias por sus comentarios.